# How to use Distance Matrix Service in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, google-api, google-map

We have built a rental based website using Magento 2.3. When we create a rental product via admin, we can put the pickup address for that product. Now, we want to show a approximate distance from the end user to the pickup address in product page.

We came to know there is service in google called Distance matrix service. How to use this service in Magento to show the above said thing?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> To configure Google Maps Distance Matrix Service:

You do not need a Google account to get started. The process includes Google account and project creation if needed. This option requires a billing account and payment method added to your Google account to complete configurations and use the algorithm.

> Step 1: Create the Google API Key

The key is from the [Google Maps Platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) and should have [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) and [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) enabled. For details, see [Configuring Distance Priority Algorithm](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-configure-distance-priority.html).

- Visit [Google Maps Platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) and click Get Started.
- To enable the platform, select Maps, Routes, and Places and click
  Continue.
  [image]

  Google Maps Platform for your Key
- Sign in with a Google account or create a new account.
- Set up a project:

  - Select a project or enter a new project name.
  - Select Yes to accept the terms.
  - Click Next.
- Enter a billing account, or create one. You can skip and add a
  billing account later. The account is required to use this service.
- Click Console to open and configure your Google Cloud Platform
  options.

  - Open your project.
  - Expand the menu and click APIs & Services > Library.
    [image]

    Google API Services
- Search for [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) and [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start). Select and enable
  each service.
- Expand the menu and click `APIs & Services > Credentials`. Copy the
  Google API Key.

[image]

```
Google API Key Copy
```

> Step 2: Configure the Google MAP Provider

- On the Admin sidebar, click Stores. Then under Settings, choose
  Configuration.
- In the panel on the left under Catalog, choose Inventory.
- Expand  the `Distance Provider for Distance Based SSA section`, and set
  Providerto `Google MAP`.
  [image]

  Distance Providers for Distance Based SSA
- Expand the `Google Distance Provider` section, and configure the
  settings:
- Enter the Google API Key, copied from your Google Account.
- For Computation mode, select a configuration.

> When using this algorithm for shipping, if routes and data does not
>   return for the selected Computation mode (driving, bicycling, or
>   walking) for a shipment, the SSA defaults to using the Source
>   Priority. We recommend also setting the priority for sources per
>   stock.

**Option**

- **Driving**  Default setting, requests standard driving directions using
  the road network
- **Walking**  Requests walking directions using pedestrian paths and
  sidewalks (where available)
- **Bicycling** `Requests bicycling directions using bicycle paths and
  preferred streets (where available). The Distance Matrix Service is
  currently only available in the US and some Canadian cities`.

For Value, select a value type:

**Option**

- **Distance** Default setting, returns the distance between points in
  metrics (kilometers and meters) or imperial (miles and feet)
- **Time to Destination**  Returns the time required to travel from the
  source locations to the shipping address in hours and minutes

[image]
Google Distance Provider

When complete, click Save Config .

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-configure-distance-priority.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I show the distance from source to destination in frontend?